# Getting error: sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `.'

Tags: bash, shell, sed

EDIT: FIXED. Now concerned with optimizing the code.

I am writing a script to separate data from one file into multiple files. When I run the script, I get the error: "sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `.'" without any line number, making it somewhat hard to debug. I have checked the lines in which I use sed individually, and they work without problem. Any ideas? I realize that there are a lot of things that I did somewhat unconventionally and that there are faster ways of doing some things (I'm sure there's a way to avoid continuously importing somefile), but right now I'm just trying to understand this error. Here is the code:

```
x1=$(sed -n '1p' < somefile | cut -f1)
y1=$(sed -n '1p' < somefile | cut -f2)
p='p'
for i in 1..$(seq 1 $(cat "somefile" | wc -l)) 
do
  x2=$(sed -n $i$p < somefile | cut -f1)
  y2=$(sed -n $i$p < somefile | cut -f1)
  if [ "$x1" = "$x2" ] && [ "$y1" = "$y2" ];
  then
    x1=$x2
    y1=$x2
  fi
  s="$(sed -n $i$p < somefile | cut -f3) $(sed -n $i$p < somefile | cut$
  echo $s >> "$x1-$y1.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause of the problem:

```
for i in 1..$(seq 1 $(cat "somefile" | wc -l))
```

Try just

```
for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -l < somefile))
```

However, you are reading your file many, many times too often with all those sed commands. Read it just once:

```
read x1 y1 < <(sed 1q somefile)
while read x2 y2 f3 f4; do
    if [[ $x1 = $x2 && $y1 = $y2 ]]; then
        x1=$x2
        y1=$x2
    fi
    echo "$f3 $f4"
done < somefile > "$x1-$y1.txt"
```

The line where you construct the `s` variable is truncated -- I'm assuming you have 4 fields per line.

Note: a problem with cut-and-paste coding is that you introduce errors: you assign `y2` the same field as `x2`

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Your corrections should speed it up significantly as well.

Comment: Now it's giving me: script2.sh: 1: script2.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected. Know why that is?

Comment: Also, I wasn't cutting and pasting, actually. I just forget which one I was looking at. Thanks for pointing that out though. I didn't catch that either.

Comment: Re: "redirection unexpected" -- what interpreter are you using to execute the script? sh or bash? Hint: search stackoverflow for the string `"redirection unexpected"`

Comment: I already tried adding #!/bin/bash to the top, and when that didn't fix anything, switched it to #!/bin/sh. The error popped up with both.

Comment: Do you execute the script like `./program` or `sh program`?

Comment: sh program. I'll try the other way.

Comment: It was telling me "Command not found," so I tried bash program, and no runtime syntax errors there. Thanks.

Comment: The name it gives is a bit off though, and when x1!=x2 or y1!=y2 it does not create a new file.

Comment: I wondered about the logic of your `if` statement -- double check your logic

Comment: You can `chmod u+x program` then invoke it with `./program` (or `path/to/program`) if the first line is `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
for i in 1..$(seq 1 $(cat "somefile" | wc -l))
```

If `somefile` were to have 3 lines, then this would result in following values of `i`:

```
1..1
2
3
```

Clearly, something like `sed -n 1..1p < filename` would result in the error you are observing: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: '.'`

You rather want:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $(cat "somefile" | wc -l))
```